# (C#) LINQ — Cannot find any result with method .Contains()

Tags: c#, linq, webforms

I have two queries for searching `Authors` by names and `Books` by title. The first one is working as expected, which is looking if any authors' name contains my input. For some reason, I cannot do the same with the books' title. I receive an error saying I cannot act on `char` when I know **it is** a `string`...

The only difference between them is that I am using a `List<string> Names` and a `string Title`

---

### Query by `Author names` (working)

```cs
author = from book in Serialisation.Books
         where book.Author.Names.Any(author => author.Contains(InputBook.Text))
         select book;
```

When I hover on `author => author` it tells me it's a string parameter. The property Names is a `List<string> Names` because some books may have 2 authors. I am capable of finding any authors' names that corresponds to a search with only one letter.

*For example : « M » outputs => Margaret Atwood*

---

### Query by `Book titles` (not working)

```cs
book = from book in Serialisation.Books
       where book.Title.Any(x => x.Contains(InputBook.Text))
       select book;
```

Here, when I hover on `x => x` it tells me it's a `char` parameter, therefore I cannot use the method `.Contains()`...

**The only solution I got is to write this instead :**

```cs
book = from book in Serialisation.Books
       where book.Title == InputBook.Text
       select book;
```

Which of course is not what I want. I don't know what to change in order to make it work..

**EDIT:**
I have tried `book.Title.Contains(InputBook.Text)` and I get an error later telling me I cannot get null value when converting the output.ToList()

---

### Class Book

```cs
public class Book 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    // my other class Author is simply a list of names. 
    // I need it to override the method ToString() so that 
    // when there is two authors for the same book, I only have 
    // one string to look into for my query.
}
```

Comment: Why not use `book.Title.Contains(InputBook.Text)` ? Did I mis-understand your requirements ?

Comment: No you didn't. I have tried that but then I get a NullException no matter what I try in my input.

Comment: I think you need to ignore culture case for this. Take a look at the @tymtam answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where book.Title.Any(x => x.Contains(searchTerm))
```

would not compile because you're deconstructing Title into a collection of chars. It says: give me all books that have a title for which each character contains my search term.

I think you want

```
where book.Title.Contains(searchTerm))
```

This says: give me all books with a title which contains the search term.

From your comments it seems that there are books with titles which are null. In this case wee need to guard against that, otherwise `Title.Contains` will throw `NullReferenceException`

```
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(book.Title) &&
               book.Title.Contains(searchTerm)
```

This says: give me all books with a title which is not null and is not empty and contains searchTerm.

Finally, you may want to ensure that the search is case-insensitive.

```
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(book.Title) &&
               book.Title.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

## Test

```
string searchTerm = "Adventures";
var books = new [] { 
    new Book{Title = "Adventures in Code"},
    new Book{Title = "My adventures in Oz"},
    new Book{Title = "About Linq"},
    new Book{Title = null} // no title
    };
var found = from book in books
        where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(book.Title) &&
               book.Title.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        select book;
foreach( var b in found ) Console.WriteLine(b.Title);
```

### Output

```
Adventures in Code
My adventures in Oz
```

Comment: I have tried that also since I was not getting any error. Upon testing, I get a nullException because the value cannot be null. I have tested only with a few letters and with the full title. Both are null.

Comment: Addded null handling. Books with not title are not something I'd expect, tbh.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the IsNullOrEmpty on the property. But now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Your property `Title` is a `string` and in most languages including `C#`, `string` is in fact an array of `char`

The `linq` query `Any` is iterating on the array so since the property is a `string` which in itself is a `char[]` i check if `Any` or the `char` match the predicate.

What you are looking for is comparing the string itself if it contains the other string. therefor you need to use :

```
where book.Title.Contains(InputBook.Text)
```